# input is not changing in iteration

Tags: python

In the code below, I am trying to input the number (e.g. 2 3 4). Suppose if the length of the input is not equal to mat_dim_col, I want to input again. However, the function is retaining the previous input and not returning the latest one.

#### Matrix row entry function.

```
def mat_row(mat_dim_col,r):
    inp = input("Enter " + 
                str(mat_dim_col) + 
                " values, all space seperated for row " + 
                str(r) + " : " ).split()
    print(inp)
    if len(inp) == mat_dim_col:
        print(inp)
        row_ent = [int(x) for x in inp]
        return row_ent 
    else:
        print("Invalid entry, try again!")
        mat_row(mat_dim_col,r)
```

Comment: This snippet seems to work perfectly for me. Can you show an example where it fails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you recurse, you need to `return` the value it provides, otherwise, you might end up getting a correct response after a few attempts but it won't be returned through the stack correctly.

```py
def mat_row(mat_dim_col,r):
    inp = input("Enter " + 
                str(mat_dim_col) + 
                " values, all space seperated for row " + 
                str(r) + " : " ).split()
    print(inp)
    if len(inp) == mat_dim_col:
        print(inp)
        row_ent = [int(x) for x in inp]
        return row_ent 
    else:
        print("Invalid entry, try again!")
        """ RETURN mat_row response """
        return mat_row(mat_dim_col,r)
```